# jquery correct spelling error in tag

Tags: jquery, html, select, replace

I have a dynamically created select tag (for a shopping cart). I found a spelling error in the dynamically created select tag that stops it being a mandatory field. I can't fix it server side as I have no access to the source. The spelling of `manatory="1"` should be `mandatory="1"`. So I tried to change that spelling with *jquery*.
Can anyone suggest how this should be done? An option could be to add (rather than replace) `mandatory="1"` to the select tag, but I'm unsure how that's done either.

I tried and failed using:

```
<script>
  (document).ready(function() {$( "select.input-medium.manatory"  ).replaceWith
       ( "<select class="input-medium" manatory="1">" ););
</script>
```

Here's the offending HTML. The options and values are dynamic too, so I can't easily rewrite the whole thing.

```
<div class="catProdAttributeItem">
  <select class="input-medium" manatory="1">
    <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
    <option value="1">1 </option>
    <option value="2">2 </option>
    <option value="3">3 </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you file a bug report within your company?

Comment: Something about this is humorous to me.

Comment: I agree it is kind of funny. And yes, bug report filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixing a miss-spelled attribute with jquery is the wrong way to solve this problem, however, if you must, all you have to do is add a new attribute and remove the old one.

```
$("select[manatory]").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr("mandatory", $this.attr("manatory")).removeAttr("manatory");
});
```

Your original attempt will work too, if you fix your quote problem. However, your attempt is likely to cause other issues or be a maintenance problem later.

Comment: Thanks for that Kevin B. Much appreciated! I tested it and it still did not change it. Hmmm.

Comment: that's likely because whatever is inspecting this element has already happened by the time this code runs. Try changing where this code is located.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select.input-medium["manatory"]').attr('mandatory','1').removeAttr('manatory');
```

It actually is unlikely that you even need to remove the "manatory" attribute and could get away with:

```
$('select.input-medium["manatory"]').attr('mandatory','1');
```

Here is a function you could add to the submit button:

```
$('SUBMIT BUTTON ID HERE').click(function(e) {
    if($('select.input-medium').val() == 'YOUR UNSELECTED VALUE HERE') {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('You need to select something.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Pathfinder, appreciate that. Makes perfect sense. But still no luck.

Comment: are you able to determine if the "mandatory" field gets added by the code I wrote? Since you are doing this at run time, it is possible that even adding the mandatory tag will not make the code you are expecting to have run do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: You might need to add a function on the click of the submit button that handles that particular item. I will add it to my answer.